# return raw sql as dictionary

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dictionary, system.reflection

Hello everyone I'm trying to write code that can get select table information with (string)tableName, but i get error when i try to put value to Dictionary. 
P.S : I have generated EF DB model.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<object>> GetTableInformation(string tableName, FinkonaDatabaseType type)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<object>> _returnableDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
        PropertyInfo prop = optimumEntities.GetType().GetProperty(tableName);
        Type tableType = prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        var items = optimumEntities.Database.SqlQuery(tableType, "SELECT * FROM " + tableName);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (!_returnableDictionary.ContainsKey(info.Name))
                {
                    _returnableDictionary.Add(info.Name, new List<object>());
                }
                _returnableDictionary[info.Name].Add(info.GetValue(info, null)); 
                // System.Reflection.TargetException, Object does not match target type.
            }
        }
        return _returnableDictionary;
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to select all of the items out of a specific table, but providing the table name only, but get back all of the records for it as an `object` type?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz Yes you are right. :) But without knowing any types :S

Comment: How are you deciding what the key is? First column????

Comment: @ZigmantasDuoba: The beauty of EF is that you don't have to do this. I'd recommend using raw ADO.NET and DataTables to get this data.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson the keys is the columns names values is values of that columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ADO.NET DataTables will be easier here, as EF is used for strongly typing data. Since you are not too worried about the data types coming back, a DataTable will be easier to navigate.

Here is an examples of this:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<object>> GetTableInformation(string tableName, FinkonaDatabaseType type)
{
   var sqlText = "SELECT * from " + tableName;
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   // Use DataTables to extract the whole table in one hit
   using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlText, optimumEntities.Database.ConnectionString)
   {
      da.Fill(dt);   
   }

   var tableData = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

   // Go through all columns, retrieving their names and populating the rows
   foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
   {
      string columnName = dc.Name;
      rowData = new List<object>();
      tableData.Add(columnName, rowData);

      foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
      {
         rowData.Add(dr[columnName]);   
      }
   }

   return tableData;
}
```